# Why the bandgap of inorganic semiconductors decreases with temperature?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

The temperature dependence of the energy bandgap in **inorganic** semiconductors is [given by](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/eband5.htm)

$$E_g (T) = E_{g,0} - \frac{\alpha T^2}{T+\beta}$$

where $\alpha, \beta$ are both positive, and the (somewhat vague) suggested reason is:

> An increased interatomic spacing decreases the potential seen by the
>   electrons in the material, which in turn **reduces** the size of the
>   energy bandgap. A direct modulation of the interatomic distance, such
>   as by applying high compressive (tensile) stress, also causes an
>   increase (decrease) of the bandgap.

On the other hand, it is known that increased spacing in **organic** semiconductors reduces energy level splitting which in turn **increases** the bandgap.

The first explanation doesn't make sense to me, while the second one does. So what is the reason that in inorganic semiconductors the energy gap decreases with temperature, even though the energy splitting decreases with temperature?